# How to increment a variable based on a column parsed from a list of files in a directory

Tags: c#, foreach

I'm trying to create an import file based on a list of files in a directory. The problem is now I've been asked to increment the value of one of the output directories based on a specific part of the file name.

Below the `LinkName` is hard coded to `Full Image_0`.  I actually want it to be more like `LinkName = "Full Image_" + intXYZ.toString();`

`intXYZ` would be a variable that starts at 0 and goes up by 1 for each file with identical `PartNums`.

Here is relevant code:

```
ImageName = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\192.168.0.144\iApps_Final_Images\ProductImages\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

ImageItem = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\192.168.0.144\iApps_Final_Images\ProductImages\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(file => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)).ToArray();

// Set path for output file and open
FilePath = @"\\vhome\public\p21\Images.txt";
var writer = new StreamWriter(FilePath);

// Go through each file found (not named thumbs) and output row of data needed for inv_mast_links import

foreach (var item in ImageName)
   {
   SetNum = SetNum + 1;
   LinkPath = item.ToString();
   PartNum = ImageItem[SetNum - 1].ToString().Split('_').Last();
   LinkName = "Full Image_0";
   var line = SetNum + delimiter + PartNum + delimiter + LinkName + delimiter + LinkPath + delimiter + "Item Maintenance";
   if (PartNum != "Thumbs") 
      {
      writer.WriteLine(line);
      }
   }

// Close the output file
writer.Close();
```

Example:  If files in directory are: `TVImage_567.jpg`, `FrontView_888.jpg`, `BackView_888.jpg` 
then since two of the images are for the same `PartNum` of 888 the desired three `LinkName` outputs would be: `Full Image_0`, `Full Image_0`, `Full Image_1`.

Comment: Your example is not clear. Please explain a bit more.

Comment: According to your code, there are some files that are named `something_Thumbs`, is that correct ? Although it isn't relevant to the actual problem, it is confusing because your variable/property is named `PartNum` and could actually be a word. You should always mention the type of the variables for which you didn't include the initialization. Makes thing clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly this is what you want:

```
Dictionary<string, Integer> counts = new Dictionary<string, Integer>();

foreach (var item in ImageName)
{
    SetNum = SetNum + 1;
    LinkPath = item.ToString();
    PartNum = ImageItem[SetNum - 1].ToString().Split('_').Last();
    if (counts.ContainsKey(PartNum)) {
        counts[PartNum]++;
    }
    else
    {
        counts.Add(PartNum, 0);
    }
    LinkName = "Full Image_" + counts[PartNum];
    var line = SetNum + delimiter + PartNum + delimiter + LinkName + delimiter + LinkPath + delimiter + "Item Maintenance";
    if (PartNum != "Thumbs") 
    {
        writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

It is not quite clear what `SetNum` does so I just left it there. The idea is simply to store your the previous item's "number" and increment a counter until the actual "number" isn't equal to the previous one.

Comment: Here let's use this example data, the file names are:  FrontView_888.jpg, TV_567.jpg, VCR_254.jpg, BackView_888.jpg, Stereo_46.jpg, SideView_888.jpg                  Then the resulting LinkNames would be:  Full Image_0, Full Image_0, Full Image_0, Full Image_1, Full Image_0, Full Image_2

Comment: @Bert then you'll want to use a `map`

Comment: Good way to think of it, these are file names of images that I have no control of what names people might give them or when they might add new ones but I need every item's FIRST image found to be named Full Image_0, ONLY items that I find a 2nd image for, the 2nd image will be named Full Image_1, and so on...

Comment: Mat - please explain more, possible show example of how?

Comment: @Bert Sure, I dont have time right now, I will edit my post probably in about 2-3h.

Comment: @Bert There I made a quick edit, didn't have time to verify it but you'll get the point.

Comment: Nope, same problem as before... This still assumes the file names are going to be in PartNum order, they are NOT going to be.

Comment: Ergo, using my example data: when it got to file BackView_888.jpg your lastnum was equal to 254 (due to item VCR_254.jpg) and partnum was equal to 888.  Since lastNum.Equals(PartNum) = false, it doesn't run the code to add to the counter....

Comment: @Bert Yeah fixed it, no need for `lastNum`, was in a rush. This should work

Answer (score 0):

How about this, You dont require a SetNum

```
       string[] ImageNames = Directory.GetFiles(@"Source-Directory\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        string[] ImageItem = ImageNames.Select(file => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)).ToArray();

        string FilePath = @"Destination.txt";
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(FilePath))
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < ImageNames.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                string LinkPath = ImageNames[i].ToString();
                string PartNum = ImageItem[i - 1].ToString().Split('_').Last();

                string LinkName = "Full Image_" + i;
                var line = i + delimiter + PartNum + delimiter + LinkName + delimiter + LinkPath + delimiter + "Item Maintenance";
                if (PartNum != "Thumbs")
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Would not would, Full Image_# would simply always count up and I need it to ALWAYS be zero UNLESS that PartNum already has a zero, than it needs to be 1, unless it already has 1, etc...